# Коректний переклад digitalization?

Tags: переклад, from-english

*Digitalization* означає переведення змісту медій у всіх його формах — текстовій, графічній, звуковій — у цифровий формат, зрозумілий сучасним комп’ютерам.

В контексті реформ цей термін може використовуватись для визначення процесу переводу державних послуг в електронний формат, а також для використання електронного документообігу замість паперового.

В різних джерелах використовуються варіанти *цифровізація*, *диджитилізація* та *інформатизація*, а у випадку прикметника *digital* як *цифровий* та *диджитальний*. Чи можна вважати ці переклади усталеними та коректними, чи є інші аналоги?

Також цікаво, як можна перекласти *Digital Agenda for Ukraine* в контексті створення стратегії цифровізації/диджиталізації для України? Досить вживаний варіант *цифрова адженда України* мені не подобається, натомість подобається варіанти *стратегія інформатизації для України* або *інформаційна стратегія для України*.

Comment: Безпосередньо в цифровій адженді (Цифрова адженда України – 2020 («Цифровий порядок денний» – 2020) використовується термін "цифровізація".

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, читаючи цей документ і виникло питання, оскільки автори вживають різні варінати в документах, дописах в соціальних мережах, ЗМІ тощо.

Comment: @sashaeve так, термін не офіційний. Але, наскільки я розумію, Адженда невдовзі буде затверджена, і термін увійде в ужиток. Більше того, на підставі цього "цифровізація" як термін впроваджується і тлумачиться в проекті Концепції з розвитку електронної демократії.

Comment: @sashaeve "Стратегія інформатизації" видається прийнятним варіантом, але, як на мене, термін "інформатизація" дещо вужчий, аніж "цифровізація" чи "диджиталізація" з огляду на перспективи охоплення найрізноманітніших сфер життя. Якщо ж розглядати варіант "інформаційна стратегія", то тоді все ж краще пропонувати "інформатизаційна стратегія" (від "інформатизація", а не "інформація").

Comment: @sashaeve в проекті Концепції з розвитку електронної демократії "цифровізація" тлумачиться як "механізм (платформа) розвитку інформаційного суспільства, внутрішнього ринку інформаційно-комунікаційних технологій шляхом підвищення ефективності та збільшення продуктивності від використання цифрових технологій, забезпечення кожному рівних можливостей доступу до інформації, знань і послуг, підвищення довіри та безпеки при використанні інформаційно-комунікаційних технологій"

Comment: Digital Agenda for Ukraine без розуміння контексту правильно перевести важко. Найбільш буквально "точне інформаційна стратегія для України". Але контекст важливий. Тому що що таке Digital Agenda for Ukraine або не ясно або може мати багато значення

Comment: @Regfor, ось тут контекст: https://www.facebook.com/valeriy.fischuk/posts/1678033522489657

Answer (score 6):

[оцифрування](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F), на мій погляд, звучить найбільш плавно і передає суть.
[В Національній бібліотеці України імені В. І. Вернадського](http://www.nbuv.gov.ua/taxonomy/term/528) у відповідному розділі використовується цей термін, він навіть використовується як тег.

Answer (score 6):

Маючи наступний контекст:

> ...Сьогодні відбулися слухання у профільному комітеті щодо «Цифрової адженди України».  Була можливість презентувати суть
>   ініціативи та законодавчі пропозиції. Мета залишається та сама:
>   рухатися у цифрову економіку та почати реалізовувати форсований
>   сценарій цифровізації.

Найкращими відповідниками, як і зазначно в питанні, можуть бути *стратегія інформатизації для України* або *інформаційна стратегія для України*. Але аж ніяк *Цифрова адженда України*.

Говорячи про переклад слово *digitalization* в залежность від контексту може мати різні значення, і як *оцифровування*, і як *інформатизація* чи *впровадження інформаційних технологій*, можливі інші варіанти. Слово [digitalization](http://www.igi-global.com/dictionary/digitalization/7748) використовується в тому ж значенні, що і його англійський відповідник, тому тлумачення з англійської теж може допомогти в перекладі. Слово також є [медичним терміном](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/digitalization#medicalDictionary), тому контекст дуже важливий.

Наведу деякі приклади (взяті з [linguee.com](http://www.linguee.com/english-german/translation/digitalization.html)):

> Increasing digitalization of media content is leading to new channels
>   and distribution routes nationally and internationally

Оцифровування медіа контенту відкриває нові способи та шляхи розповсюдження на національному та міжнародному рівнях.

> The digitalization of television opens the door to new possibilities
>   for the transmission of added services. ([constantin-medien.de](http://www.constantin-medien.de/dasat/images/0/100780-gb2008-e-08-290409-safe.pdf))

Цифрове телебачення відкриває двері нових можливостей для передавання додаткових сервісів.

> The answer of the automotive industry is digitalization throughout the
>   entire life cycle and linking design with production ([siemens.com](http://www.siemens.com/industryjournal/pool/industry_journal/1599_Magazin_e_RZ.pdf))

Відповіддю автомобільної галузі є впровадження інформаційних технологій в життєвий цикл і поєднання дизайну (прим. або проектування) і виробництва.

> Now that the "digitalization of logistics" - this is how Chinese refer
>   to the combination of logistics and IT - is in full swing, looking at
>   the supply chain as a whole and optimizing the overall logistic costs
>   are two factors that are gaining importance. (sysbiomed.org)

Тепер, коли інформатизація (в сенсі впровадження інформаційних технологій) логістики - те, що китайці відносять до поєднання логістики та ІТ, йде повним ходом, ланцюжок постачання як ціле та оптимізації загальних кошт логістики - це два фактори, які набувать більшого значення.

Comment: Наведіть, будь ласка, приклади, коли потрібно вживати той чи інший варіант перекладу.

Answer (score 5):

Оскільки це неологізм, то коректного перекладу ще немає.

Видання словників неологізмів не встигає за стрімким розвитком технологій, особливо інформаційно-комунікаційних.

Неофіційний [Словник неологізмів](http://www.jnsm.com.ua/cgi-bin/u/book/mySIS.pl?showSISid=46609864-6427&action=showSIS&pageSISid=1#%D0%90) такого терміну не містить.

У проекті Цифрової адженди України – 2020 («Цифрового порядку денного» – 2020) використовується термін **"цифровізація"**.

Comment: Чесно говорячи, я і задав питання тут, щоб після обговорення запропонувати змінити як адженду, так і цифровізацію на щось адекватне. Тому цей проект не може слугувати авторитетним джерелом.

Comment: @sashaeve просто обговорення проекту цього документа вже вийшло на такий рівень (комітетські слухання в комітеті ВР з питань інформатизації та зв'язку - https://www.facebook.com/danchenko.oleksandr/posts/726663004177864?pnref=story), що навряд чи будуть вносити саме такі правки :( Проте, чому б не спробувати.

Comment: Там окремим пунктом йде узаконення "цифрових" дефініцій, тому впевнений, що робота над термінологією не буде марною.

Comment: @sashaeve Успіхів Вам! Якщо можна, прохання окремо повідомити про результати. Бо, як я й казала, на термінології "адженди" частково базується термінологія проекту Концепції електронної демократії. А важливо, щоб терміни були гармонізовані.

Answer (score 4):

## Діджиталізація на [пальцях](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/digitus#Latin)

*Digitalization* aka [*Digitizing*, *digitising*, *digitisation*, *digitalizing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digitizing#cite_note-1) - [приведення даних до цифрового формату](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter) для *передачі чи зберігання* у вигляді бінарного коду. Це робиться для подальшої обробки таких даних [*інформаційними системами*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_system). Тобто *Digitalization* - це всеж таки оцифровування, переведення у цифровий формат.

У випадку коли **оцифровується процес**, то у цифрову форму переходять частини [*алгоритму*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm) або [*регламенту*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic) такого процесу, тобто [*програмуються*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_programming).

Явище, під час якого **збільшується роль інформації** (у будь якій формі, просто у формі цифрових даних інформацію зручніше обробляти) у справах суспільства, економіки або території називається [*Інформатизація*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informatization)

Тобто **інформатизація** - широке, стратегічне, цивілізаційне явище, в той час як **діджиталізація** - не більше ніж один із службових засобів процесу *збільшення ролі інформації у справах ...*

Comment: У мене є проект цієї Цифрової адженди, але в .pdf Я не знаю, як ним поділитися в межах цієї бети. У ньому під цифровізацією мається на увазі не стільки оцифрування (переведення інформації в цифровий формат) і не стільки інформатизація (в сенсі збільшення ролі інформації у справах суспільства), скільки всеохоплююче розповсюдження ІКТ в найрізноманітніші сфери - освіта, медицина, урядування, демократія (петиції, референдуми, вибори), економіка, комерція, митниця, землеробство, безпека і ще багато-багато сфер.

Comment: Я не стверджую, що "цифровізація" влучний відповідник, але й "оцифрування", й "інформатизація" не розкривають змісту згідно з концепцією.

Comment: навіщо тоді на отой процес витрачати зусилля, в чому бенефіт?

Comment: Автор запитання => "Чесно говорячи, я і задав питання тут, щоб після обговорення запропонувати змінити як адженду, так і цифровізацію на щось адекватне. Тому цей проект не може слугувати авторитетним джерелом. – sashaeve 1 hour ago"

Comment: я про аґенду взагалом, про "всеохоплююче розповсюдження ІКТ в найрізноманітніші сфери - освіта, медицина, урядування, демократія (петиції, референдуми, вибори), економіка, комерція, митниця, землеробство, безпека"

Comment: Як один з авторів цього документу можу сказати, що термінологічно це питання не вирішено. Було би просто чудово визначитись одразу з терміном, що означає перехід до електронних процесів. Далі буде набагато простіше

Comment: Формула назви в моєму розумінні ::= "стратегія|aґенда|план `кодове словосполучення`", де `кодове словосполучення` - це те словосполучення, яке якщо прибрати його з мотиваційної частини, то весь цей план втрачає сенс. А отими діґіталізаціями та інформатизаціями зручно тільки прикривати <s>освоєння бюджету</s> прогалини у мотиваційній частині

Answer (score 2):

Шукаємо переклади слова *digitalization*:

[Lingvo](http://www.lingvo.ua/uk/Translate/en-uk/digitalization): перетворення даних у цифрову форму; дигіталізація.

[E2U](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=digitalization&dicts=all&highlight=on): цифрува́ння, зацифрува́ння, кодува́ння, закодува́ння (ана́логової інформа́ції); дигіталізація.

[Yenotes](https://www.yenotes.com/uk/?from_lang=en&q=digitalization&to_lang=uk): інформатизація, оцифрування.

Перший варіант перекладу, наданий Lingvo, є занадто масивним, другий - для медичної термінології.

E2U оперує поняттями, якими ніхто не користується, але вже близький до істини.

Yenotes, хоч і створений суспільними зусиллями людей, надає два найбільш поширених переклади: [інформатизація](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F) і [оцифрування](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F).

Оцифрування не підходить для вашого конкретного випадку тим, що це не створення електронної системи для переходу від паперового обігу до електронного, а просто переведення (будь-якої) інформації в цифрову форму. То ж, залишається інформатизація.

До конкретного прикладу з *Digital Agenda for Ukraine*:

*Цифрова адженда України* мені не подобається так само, як і вам.

Щодо наступних двох варіантів, *стратегія інформатизації для України* й *інформаційна стратегія для України*: вони не синонімічні, не тотожні. Коли *стратегію інформатизації для України* дійсно можна сприймати як стратегію переведення систем на ІТ-системи у всіх сферах, то *інформаційну стратегію для України* можна сприйняти і як те, чим займається [міністерство інформаційної політики україни](http://mip.gov.ua), тобто, як стратегію діяльності держави Україна на міжнародному і внутрішньому інформаційних полях.

Тому, задля того, щоби унеможливити хибне прочитання (а також для забезпечення українського її звучання), залишається користуватися перекладом *стратегія інформатизації для України*.

**Суб’єктивно**:

Або вигадувати новий. Що, одначе, особисто мені видається непотрібним.

Comment: Перепрошую, не всі забули, що "інформація" й "інформатизація" не синоніми :) => "@sashaeve "Стратегія інформатизації" видається прийнятним варіантом, але, як на мене, термін "інформатизація" дещо вужчий, аніж "цифровізація" чи "диджиталізація" з огляду на перспективи охоплення найрізноманітніших сфер життя. Якщо ж розглядати варіант "інформаційна стратегія", то тоді все ж краще пропонувати "інформатизаційна стратегія" (від "інформатизація", а не "інформація"). – Oksana Gubrenko 6 hours ago"

Comment: У мене є проект цієї Цифрової адженди, але в .pdf Я не знаю, як ним поділитися в межах цієї бети. У ньому під цифровізацією мається на увазі не стільки оцифрування (переведення інформації в цифровий формат) і не стільки інформатизація (в сенсі збільшення ролі інформації у справах суспільства), скільки всеохоплююче розповсюдження ІКТ в найрізноманітніші сфери - освіта, медицина, урядування, демократія (петиції, референдуми, вибори), економіка, комерція, митниця, землеробство, безпека і ще багато-багато сфер.

Comment: Я не стверджую, що "цифровізація" влучний відповідник, але й "оцифрування", й "інформатизація" не розкривають змісту згідно з концепцією.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko ех, не відкрив коментарі до головного питання. Казав про тих, хто писав відповіді. Видалив про "забули".

Я також не впевнений, як це найкраще зробити з пдф. Може, в вас є можливість десь опублікувати його в електронному вигляді? На сайті університету, наприклад.

Comment: Я не знаю, чи його можна публікувати, адже це проект, хоча днями його вже обговорювали на комітетських слуханнях у профільному комітеті ВР. Але версія проекту 1.0. десь зустрічалася у Фейсбуку. Як знайду, скину посилання.

Comment: А ще мені сподобалося Ваше "також для забезпечення українського її звучання), залишається користуватися перекладом стратегія інформатизації для України". Стратегія й інформатизація мають таке ж українське звучання, як і диджиталізація, і цифровізація, як на мене :)

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko я так написав, бо перші два корені вже давно усталені в українській мові, а "диджиталізація" навіть вимовити складно. Не погоджуєтесь? (про цифровізацію тоді ще не йшлося)

Comment: Погоджуюся, але не з тим, що про цифровізацію тоді не йшлося :) Знову ж - коментарі до головного питання => "Безпосередньо в цифровій адженді (Цифрова адженда України – 2020 («Цифровий порядок денний» – 2020) використовується термін "цифровізація". – Oksana Gubrenko 6 hours ago" А також моя окрема відповідь про неологізми, та в самому головному питанні)

Comment: Посилання на перший проект Цифрової адженди https://issuu.com/mineconomdev/docs/digital_agenda_ukraine-v2__1_